# Adventureworks Project/solution and databases out of sync

Tags: sql-server, ssas

I am working on being able to process the adventureworks cube, and although i am, as outlined below, able to pull  the databases into sql server and retrieve the project, **I have not found a single download source for database and project/solution.**
I have outlined three steps I have taken, at each point there is a possibility I have missed something – to summarize – is it possible to get the project/solution from link1 in step1 below, is it possible to get the databases from link2 in step 2 below, or given that the db and project are out of sync, what additions to the cube structure would be necessary to correct the errors in step 3.  Re Step 3 I note that there seem to be 2 dimensions missing, dim time and dim fact sales summary, but it might be tricky to add them exactly as Microsoft has and there could be more after those are added to the project)?
**Step 1:** I have retrieved and successfully attached the AdventureWorksDW database from the following link (does anyone know how to get the project from this link?) 
**link1:** http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/59211
**Step 2**: I have retrieved the adventureworks solution from the following link (does anyone know how to get the databases from this link?.. as i discuss below although i have turned on filestream and databases seem to be created i dont know how to get them into my sql server instance..sigh) 
**Link 2:** http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlanalysisservices/thread/87fc44d2-80ac-49aa-a9c1-c3302935aafc/
However, even though I have turned filestream on , and I see the create scripts running, the databases are not created in my sql server instance (is there a special trick to this? How do you point the scripts to the correct SQL server connection? Or is there an attach step?) 
**Step 3:** When I process the cube from sources in steps1 and 2 I get the following errors:
OLE DB error: OLE DB or ODBC error: Invalid object name 'dbo.DimTime'.; 42S02.Errors in the OLAP storage engine:
 An error occurred while the dimension, with the ID of 'Dim Time', Name of 'Date' was being processed.
Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the 'Fiscal Year' attribute of the 'Date' dimension from the 'Adventure Works DW' database was being processed.
OLE DB error: OLE DB or ODBC error: Operation canceled; HY008.
Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the dimension, with the ID of 'Fact Sales Summary', Name of 'Sales Channel' was being processed.
Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the 'Sales Channel' attribute of the 'Sales Channel' dimension from the 'Adventure Works DW' database was being processed.